# Django: How to render image with a template

Tags: python, django, cairo, pycairo, cairoplot

Objective: I would like to display a generated .png image using a template.

I worked with the example [here](http://pyrho.tumblr.com/post/1284834101/cairoplot-and-django). Here is the final snippet of code from that example:

```
def gen_chart(request):
    ...
    pp = CairoPlot.PiePlot(surface, data, heigth, width, background = None, gradient = True, shadow = True, series_colors = colors )
    pp.render()

    response = HttpResponse(mimetype="image/png")
    pp.surface.write_to_png(response)

    return response
```

Accessing the `gen_chart` view shows a pretty pie chart. However, I'd like to render this using a template, so I can add more data in the resulting page (Labels, description, headers, and other html stuff).

I found a related solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327204/how-to-convert-a-django-httpresponse-to-a-django-render-call). In that solution, it recommends to do something like this:

```
c = RequestContext(request,{'result':json.dumps(result)})
t = Template("{{result}}") # A dummy template
response = HttpResponse(t.render(c), mimetype = u'application/json')
return response
```

I tried to adapt that code as follows:

```
c = RequestContext(request, {'result': pp.surface.write_to_png(response)})
t = Template('test_app/pie_chart_template.html')
response = HttpResponse(t.render(c), mimetype="image/png")
return response
```

But as you may have guessed, I ran into the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'response' referenced before assignment`, since the `response` variable doesn't exist when creating `c`.

What is the correct way to creating an image and pass it to a template to render?

Comment: Save it to a file and use an img tag.... Or put your view_chart URL as the src in an img tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already have a  working `gen_chart` view that creates your image as png why not just add a

```
<img src='{% url "gen_chart" %}' />
```

to your HTML template and render it normally ? You are you trying to make your life difficult ?

Comment: That would amount to insanity. It's my lack of understanding I'm doing it the wrong way. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: It's easy if you think of it simply: Your ``gen_chart`` view is *actually* an image. So if you include it to *any* html (not just django templates) it will display that image !

Comment: Excellent, that worked. Thanks for the explanation, it definitely helps to grasp the concept.